# Заполнение файла случайными числами и подсчет количества повторений каждого числа (С++)

Tags: c++, fstream

Задание - "Заполнить файл случайными числами (n - количество чисел в файле, m - количество чисел в строке) и подсчитать, сколько раз каждое число встречается в тексте файла number_file1.txt. Все встречающиеся числа и их количество вывести в файл number_file2.txt и на консоль в формате «число – количество». В конец файла number_file2.txt добавить слова "Result = " и количество различных чисел в тексте."

С заполнением файла я справился, а вот дальше дела не идут....Помогите, пожалуйста, с подсчетом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n, m,count=0;
    int lL = -100, uL = 100;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "m = ";
    cin >> m;
    ofstream fout_acc("number_file1.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int r = lL + rand() % (uL - lL + 1);
        if (count == m) 
        {
            cout << "\n" << r << " ";
            fout_acc << "\n" << r << " ";
            count = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << r << " ";
            fout_acc << r << " ";
        }
        count++;
    }
    fout_acc.close();
}
```

Comment: P.S. я смог найти код, для подсчета, но не могу его присоединить к своему(

Comment: А если использовать map с парами чиcло:количество?

Comment: У вас не такой уж большой диапазон. Сделайте массив с соответствующим количеством элементов, и увеличивайте всякий раз при генерации значение соответствующего элемента.